# How to put a variable in the header section of a v-data-table from a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, frontend, vuetify.js

I'm working on an app in Vue.js with datatables, and i need to show the headers of a v-data-table component but i need (if it's possible) to pass a variable that can change with the language of the page.

Here's my portion of code that shows the headers

```
    headers: [
    { text: "Name", sortable: true, value: "name" },
    { text: "Lastname", sortable: true, value: "last_name" },
    { text: "Email", sortable: true, value: "email" },
    { text: "Role", sortable: true, value: "roles[0].name" },
    { text: "Actions", sortable: false, align: "center" }
  ],
```

I have a JavaScript file in another directory that contains the variables and i import it in my script section like this:
`import message from "../../lang/index.js";`

How can i include the variables i need in the `text` field of headers?

EDIT: [The app looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLL3u.png)

I need that instead of showing the headers in English (i.e. "Name", "Lastname") i need to show them in spanish ("Nombre") and i don't want to hardcode the info in the text field of the headers.

Also [this is how looks my javascript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3505.png) where are the variables to access (there are a lot of them)
This is my first task in my first work, the app were already built, i'm only making basic work of puting variables here and there

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome to StackOverflow. I need more context to answer this. Specifically, what does it look like now, and what do you want it to look like? And what is the contents of the message file '../../lang/index.js'? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for comment. I edit the question with more info

Comment: Can you please share the complete component code of data-table, that would really help to solve the issue..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the properties of an object (imported or local) using two kinds of accessors: Dot notation and bracket notation. The below Mozilla doc explains them clearly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Bracket notation provides more freedom when accessing properties inside an object.

Let's say you have a Vue component's with a language selector dropdown and a data-table.

Your `data` block looks like this:

```js
data() {
    return {
        language: "en",
        languageOptions: ["en", "es"],
        headers: [
            { text: "Name", sortable: true, value: "name" },
            { text: "Lastname", sortable: true, value: "last_name" },
            { text: "Email", sortable: true, value: "email" },
            { text: "Role", sortable: true, value: "roles[0].name" },
            { text: "Actions", sortable: false, align: "center" }
        ],
    }
}
```

And for your `messages.js` file:

```
export default {
    en: {
        name: "Name",
        lastName: "Last Name",
        role: "Role",
        email: "Email",
        actions: "Actions"
    },
    es: {
        name: "Nombre",
        number: "Numero",
        role: "El Oficio"
        email: "Email",
        actions: "Acción"
    }
}
```

To replace the header texts with a value from the corresponding language option

`messages[language][fieldName]`:

Modified code:

```
data() {
    return {
        language: "en",
        languageOptions: ["en", "es"],
        headers: [
            { text: messages[language]["name"], sortable: true, value: "name" },
            { text: messages[language]["lastName"], sortable: true, value: "last_name" },
            { text: messages[language]["email"], sortable: true, value: "email" },
            { text: messages[language]["role"], sortable: true, value: "roles[0].name" },
            { text: messages[language]["actions"], sortable: false, align: "center" }
        ],
    }
}
```

I would also suggest checking out Vue's localization plugin [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html).